# Dynamic checkbox and get the values from the checkbox checked

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-2, checkboxlist

I am having difficulty creating dynamic checkboxes from db, and getting the values from the checkboxes when checked.

I have this Controller:

```
public function proporEvento(){

    $natureza = $this->evento_model->naturezaEvento();
    $apoio = $this->evento_model->apoioPertendido();
    $espaco = $this->evento_model->espaco();
    $material = $this->evento_model->material();
    $suportgraf = $this->evento_model->suporteGrafico();
    $audiovisual = $this->evento_model->audioVisual();                  

    $data['title']              = 'Propor Evento';
    $data['naturezaEvento']     = $natureza;
    $data['apoioPertendido']    = $apoio;
    $data['espaco']             = $espaco;
    $data['material']           = $material;
    $data['suporteGraf']        = $suportgraf;
    $data['audioVisual']        = $audiovisual;



    $this->load->view('cliente/clienteheaderdash_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('cliente/clientemenu_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('cliente/clienteproporevento_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('cliente/clientefooterdash_view', $data);
}
```

Have this model:

```
public function naturezaEvento(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tblnaturezaevento');       
    return $query->result(); 
}

public function apoioPertendido(){      
    $query = $this->db->get('tblapoio');        
    return $query->result();
}

public function espaco(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tblespaco');       
    return $query->result();
}

public function material(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tblmaterial');     
    return $query->result();
}

public function suporteGrafico(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tblsuportegraf');      
    return $query->result();
}


public function audioVisual(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tblaudiovisual');      
    return $query->result();
}
```

...and I have this view (one part for example):

```
<label>Apoio Pertendido</label>
<div class="form-group">
     <?php foreach ($apoioPertendido as $row) { ?>
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" name="apoiopretendido[]" value="<?php   echo $row->idApoio  ?>" /> <?php   echo $row->descricao;  ?>
       </label>
       </br>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

this code create the `<input type="checkbox"...>` correctly but how can I get the values from checked checkbox?

My form to go with this controller function:

```
 public function etapa2(){
    //$this->load->library('form_validation');

    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('naturezaEvento', 'naturezaEvento', '|required|');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('denominacao', 'denominacao', '|required|');
    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('datainicio', 'datainicio', '|required|');
    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('horainicio', 'horainicio', '|required|');
    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('datafim', 'datafim', '|required|');
    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('datainicio', 'datainicio', '|required|');

    //if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //$this->index();
        //}else{

    $datageral['idcliente'] = $this->session->userdata('idcliente');
    $datageral['idnatureza']=$this->input->post('naturezaEvento'); //insere o id do campo natureza da tabela tblnaturezaevento
    $datageral['denominacaotitulo'] =  $this->input->post('denominacao'); 
    $datageral['datainicio']=$this->input->post('datainicio');
    $datageral['horainicio']=$this->input->post('horainicio');
    $datageral['datafim']=$this->input->post('datafim');
    $datageral['horafim']=$this->input->post('horafim');
    $datageral['planotrabalho']=$this->input->post('planotrabalho');
    $datageral['raidertecnico']=$this->input->post('raidertecnico');
    $datageral['programa']=$this->input->post('programa');
    $datageral['mesa']=$this->input->post('mesa');
    $datageral['notas']=$this->input->post('notas');
    //'valorprovisorio' => $this->input->post('notas'), TODO fazer o valor provisório

    //checkbox apoio
    $apoiopertendido = $this->evento_model->apoioPertendido();           
    foreach ($apoiopertendido as $row) {
        if ($this->input->post($row->checked, TRUE)===true){
            $datageral[$row->tag] = $this->input->post($row->tag);
            }
    }

     //checkbox espaços
    $espacopertendido = $this->evento_model->espaco();
    //$esp = array();
    foreach ($espacopertendido as $row) {
        if ($this->input->post($row->tag, TRUE)===true){
            $datageral[$row->tag] = $this->input->post($row->tag);
        }
    }

    //Material Necessário
    $material = $this->evento_model->material();
    //$materialnecessario = array();
    foreach ($material as $row) {           
        $datageral[$row->tag] = $this->input->post($row->tag);            
    }

    //checkbox suportes graficos
    $suporteGrafico = $this->evento_model->suporteGrafico();
    //$suporte = array();
    foreach ($suporteGrafico as $row) {
        if ($this->input->post($row->tag, TRUE)===true){
            $datageral[$row->tag] = $this->input->post($row->tag);
        }
    }

    //Registo Audio Visual
    $audioVisual = $this->evento_model->audioVisual();
    //$audiov = array();
    foreach ($audioVisual as $row) {
        if ($this->input->post($row->tag, TRUE)===true){
            $datageral[$row->tag] = $this->input->post($row->tag);
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('cliente/clienteheaderdash_view');
    $this->load->view('cliente/clientemenu_view');     
    $this->load->view('cliente/clienteetapa2_view', $datageral);
    $this->load->view('cliente/clientefooterdash_view');
           // }
}
```

Comment: If you _`var_dump($_POST)`_ and look for the 'checkbox' name array, you will see the values for the 'selected' checkboxes. If you need to process the 'unchecked' values then you need another way of identifying those values. Possible ways: 1) Rebuild the list of id's and mark the ones that you got back. 2) Have a 'hidden field' for each 'checkbox' that returns the id.

Comment: Thanks, but the array return is null :/

Comment: resolved, tha array is null because the class="flat_red", i remove this class and works fine thanks